# Altium Library *.LIB to *.IntLib

Tags: altium, library

I just downloaded a model from the TI website for the following component : REF3325.
I need to put it in my schematic in order to simulate it after.
But in the .rar I downloaded, there is only a *.LIB file, which I can add to my installed libraries in Altium but it says there is'nt any component in it.

Do I need to convert this file into a IntLib? Or do I have to create the component by myself ?
I don't really understand the difference between this *.LIB and the *.IntLib formats ...

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the .rar? Also there is a part about library types in [Altium techdoc](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Component,+Model+and+Library+Concepts).

Comment: Are you sure its a Altium library format and not a CADSTAR Part Library?

Comment: I think I solved my problem. I actually renamed the file extension from *.LIB to *.ckt and added it as a model simulation in a component in Altium. It looks like it should work.
I've got now another problem, which I will post in another question

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you downloaded a SPICE model, not an Altium "Library" per se.

Altium has:

- SchLib -- Schematic Library (A collection of schematic symbols)
- PcbLib -- PCB Library (A collection of footprints)
- CmpLib -- Component Library (used with Altium Vault, a collection of Components)
- IntLib -- Integrated Library, a compiled together combination of SchLib + PcbLib
- DbLib/SVNDbLib -- Libraries that hold collections of components, usually described with a database (MS Access or similar)

FWIW, even if you just have a singular symbol or footprint, it'll show up as a SchLib/PcbLib.

As you found out, you can attach models to components in Altium such as SPICE or IBIS -- if I recall correctly, that linking can be done either at the SchLib level, or I think the Vault may support linking of models at the CmpLib level as well.